# Perform Task on subset rather than filter out

Tags: r, data.table

I am performing multiple filter steps (using Variables 1-8 in my example) using data.table. I would like to change my code in a way that rather than extracting a subset of my data table I change a boolean variable (Variable 9) within the data table from TRUE to FALSE when the row would not have been extracted before.

Until now I was trying to this somehow using the data.table package but I would also be happy with a solution using another package or baseR.

One examplary filterstep which i used to extract a subset:

```
    DT_new <- DT[DT[Variable1=="M+H" & Variable2==100], on=.(Variable3,
    Variable4, Variable5)][Variable6-Variable7 >= 0 | Variable8 < 100]
```

I would like to set it up in a way that DTnew still contains all the rows (even those rejected by my filter). However, for those rows that do not meet the criteria of my filter I would like to switch the value of a Variable9 within my data table from TRUE to FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you try like this:

```
DT_tmp <- DT[Variable1=="M+H" & Variable2==100], on=.(Variable3,
    Variable4, Variable5)]

DT$Variable9 <- ifelse( (DT_tmp$Variable6-DT_tmp$Variable7 >= 0 | DT_tmp$Variable8 < 100), T, F)
```

is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Hmm isn't the `on=.(Variable3,Variable4, Variable5)` part missing then?

Comment: What exactly are you looking forward with the on=.() part?

Comment: I asked about how to set up I filter like that some time ago. The reason why it looks like that is explained here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399216/r-data-table-filter-for-rows-by-condition-in-multiple-variables]

Comment: I have edited the answer, does this make sense now? I am very impressed with the on functionality by the way ;)

Comment: Generelly works thank you :) Just replaced `DT_tmp <- DT[DT[Variable1=="M+H" & Variable2==100], on=.(Variable3,
    Variable4, Variable5)]`

Comment: But how would I do it if my filter was just `DT_new <- DT[DT[Variable1=="M+H" & Variable2==100], on=.(Variable3,
    Variable4, Variable5)]`. Because then I would not have anything to write into the `ifelse()`

Comment: Ok! good question, for what I can see in the data.table sheet from the page -> https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/  on is used to combine so if you would do: DT_tmp <- DT[DT, on=.(Variable3,
    Variable4, Variable5)] and then DT$Variable9 <- ifelse( DT_temp$Variable1=="M+H" & DT_temp$Variable2==100), T, F)

Comment: Hmm I can't do that because I would run into the Error `Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again.` because there would be more than one possibility to combine (and also only one of them would be correct)

Comment: it works if I just use a filter that extracts the whole data table :) thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186056/discussion-between-karen-and-yasel).

Comment: What is the `ifelse` for? A logical test already returns `TREU` or `FALSE`, e.g, its like doing `ifelse(2 > 1, TRUE, FLASE)` instead of just `2 > 1`